# Is there a way to set spark configuration to a mapping dataflow managed cluster/IR in Azure Data Factory/Azure Synapse?

Tags: azure, apache-spark, azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

I was trying to use delta table as my sink and I want to set the Vacuum to 0. It is throwing an error that I should first set the configuration '*spark.databricks.delta.retentionDurationCheck.enabled*':'*false*' but I can't see where I can set this property as compute clusters for mapping dataflows are created and managed by Azure at runtimes. Also, There is another configuration of spark that I want to configure based on requirement i.e, '*spark.sql.parquet.compression.codec*'. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 1):

That is not possible as the Spark environment being used by Mapping Data Flows is fully managed by the ADF service. That being said, we will be exposing more properties to the Delta connector in CY22.